# Painting cell outside row bounds

Tags: javafx, tableview, row, cell

How to paint cell outside its row bounds? I display `TextArea` in a cell of a table which must have each row of the same height. I need more space, both vertically and horizontally for that cell.

Is it possible to display cell higher than a single row?
We must use fixed height of the row (see `TableRowSkinBase.fixedCellSizeEnabled()`.
We already use modify by copy paste code of the `TableRowSkinBase` to eventually in the `TableRowSkinBase.layoutChildren` to set the size of the cell to larger than single cell in both direction. What were able to display cell wider but not heigher? We did it by `cell.resize()` method.

Comment: I forgot to tell that I relocate both cell and row at the end of its parent's children collection. I look at tree graph (ScenicView) and both cell and row are at the end as intended.